# Encrypt the inputted text in R

Tags: r

I have one problem. So I have to create a program that encrypts the inputted text by replacing every letter with the positioning number of this letter position in the alphabet (example: text=ABC, coded message = 123). How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about TEXT ie whole sentences with spaces, commas, punctuations, LF, empty lines, or (just) a single word?

Comment: There are dedicated packages for this task, also, read about `charToRaw`, and `rawToChar`.

Answer (score 2):

This works

```r
library(tidyverse)

input_string <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

for(i in 1:26) {
  
  input_string <- str_replace_all(input_string, 
                                  regex(letters[i], ignore_case = TRUE), 
                                  as.character(i)
                                  )
  
}

input_string
[1] "2085 17219311 218152314 61524 1021131619 1522518 2085 1212625 4157"
```

Or if you prefer to use [`mgsub()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48189012/5783745)

```r
devtools::install_github("bmewing/mgsub")
library(mgsub)

input_string <- "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

for(i in 1:26) {
  
  input_string <- mgsub(input_string, 
                        regex(letters[i], ignore_case = TRUE), 
                        as.character(i)
                        )
  
}

input_string
[1] "2085 17219311 218152314 61524 1021131619 1522518 2085 1212625 4157"
```

Comment: How would you decypher this message? How would you know if '11' meant 'AA' or 'K' ?

Comment: @Chris you wouldn't know. Replacement like the OP says (`ABC` with `123`) would not allow for 'decryption' (term used loosely). Could always use a separator though (e.g. a hyphen or comma between each substitution), then 'decryption' would be possible.

Comment: Of course you are right, that the question was to only replace letters with numbers. I like your approach. I was just curious if you maybe also thought about this option.

Answer (score 1):

```r
encrypt <- function(string) {
  spstring <- unlist(stringr::str_split(tolower(string), ""))
  unlist(lapply(spstring, function(x) which(x == letters)))
}

encrypt("Test")
#> [1] 20  5 19 20
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Good old base-R `sapply` based solution in case you just want to "encrypt" words and there are no special characters involved.

```
> a <- "TesT"
> sapply(unlist(strsplit(x = toupper(a), "\\b")), match, LETTERS)

 T  E  S  T 
20  5 19 20
```

Transform the word in vector `a` to upper case, run the string split on single letters `\\b` (regex) unlist the result and `sapply` the `match` function against R's (internal UPPERCASE) `LETTERS` vector. You could also turn the character string `tolower` and match it against `letters`.
Of course there is no easy way for you to "decrypt" that without having some information about the original text eg 24 could mean the letter "x" or "bd".